# While Getting Page content of other page in WordPress..... content showing without there tags in single line

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code, but its only showing the content in lines....
In this page there are content with the tags like h1 h2 and p

```
<?php
$your_query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=who-we-are' );
while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();
$content = wpautop(get_the_content());
$trimmed_content = wp_trim_words( $content, 100, NULL );
echo $trimmed_content;
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Can any one Help??

Comment: what content you want to show ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `the_content()` instead of `get_the_content()`.

Because `get_the_content()` does not pass the content through the_content. Which means that it does not auto-embed videos, or expand shortcodes, among other things.

For more help see this link : [get_the_content](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_content), [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)

I hope it will helps you. Thanks :)